# No Graph Displayed for My plotly dashboard using callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly

This is a code writing assignment for one of the courses on Coursera. The assignment is to create a dashboard of various graphics for some data (can be downloaded from a URL). I have completed the coding part of the assignment, but there seems to be no graph showing up. My guess is that there is something going on with the callback function, but that is just a wild guess. I am completely lost on where the problem could be...

The following chunk of code is already given so I doubt that there is a problem here...

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
# from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash import no_update


# Create a dash application
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
# JupyterDash.infer_jupyter_proxy_config()

# REVIEW1: Clear the layout and do not display exception till callback gets executed
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

# Read the airline data into pandas dataframe
airline_data =  pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DV0101EN-SkillsNetwork/Data%20Files/airline_data.csv', 
                            encoding = "ISO-8859-1",
                            dtype={'Div1Airport': str, 'Div1TailNum': str, 
                                   'Div2Airport': str, 'Div2TailNum': str})


# List of years 
year_list = [i for i in range(2005, 2021, 1)]

"""Compute graph data for creating yearly airline performance report 

Function that takes airline data as input and create 5 dataframes based on the grouping condition to be used for plottling charts and grphs.

Argument:
     
    df: Filtered dataframe
    
Returns:
   Dataframes to create graph. 
"""
def compute_data_choice_1(df):
    # Cancellation Category Count
    bar_data = df.groupby(['Month','CancellationCode'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    # Average flight time by reporting airline
    line_data = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['AirTime'].mean().reset_index()
    # Diverted Airport Landings
    div_data = df[df['DivAirportLandings'] != 0.0]
    # Source state count
    map_data = df.groupby(['OriginState'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    # Destination state count
    tree_data = df.groupby(['DestState', 'Reporting_Airline'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    return bar_data, line_data, div_data, map_data, tree_data


"""Compute graph data for creating yearly airline delay report

This function takes in airline data and selected year as an input and performs computation for creating charts and plots.

Arguments:
    df: Input airline data.
    
Returns:
    Computed average dataframes for carrier delay, weather delay, NAS delay, security delay, and late aircraft delay.
"""
def compute_data_choice_2(df):
    # Compute delay averages
    avg_car = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['CarrierDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_weather = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['WeatherDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_NAS = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['NASDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_sec = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['SecurityDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_late = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['LateAircraftDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    return avg_car, avg_weather, avg_NAS, avg_sec, avg_late
```

The following chunk of code is what I worked on and can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
# Application layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[ 
                                # TODO1: Add title to the dashboard
                                html.H1('US Domestic Airline Flights Performance',
                                       style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36',
                                'font-size': 24}),
    
                              
    
                                # REVIEW2: Dropdown creation
                                # Create an outer division 
                                html.Div([
                                    # Add an division
                                    html.Div([
                                        # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for report type
                                        html.Div(
                                            [
                                            html.H2('Report Type:', style={'margin-right': '2em'}),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        # TODO2: Add a dropdown
                                        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'input-type', 
                                        options=[
                                                {'label': 'Yearly Airline Performance Report', 'value': 'OPT1'},
                                                {'label': 'Yearly Airline Delay Report', 'value': 'OPT2'}
                                                ],
                                        placeholder = 'Select a report type',
                                        style = {'width': '80%', 'padding': '3px', 'font-size': '20px', 'textAlign': 'center'})
                                        
                                    # Place them next to each other using the division style
                                    ], style={'display':'flex'}),
                                    
                                   # Add next division 
                                   html.Div([
                                       # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for choosing year
                                        html.Div(
                                            [
                                            html.H2('Choose Year:', style={'margin-right': '2em'})
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        dcc.Dropdown(id='input-year', 
                                                     # Update dropdown values using list comphrehension
                                                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
                                                     placeholder="Select a year",
                                                     style={'width':'80%', 'padding':'3px', 'font-size': '20px', 'text-align-last' : 'center'}),
                                            # Place them next to each other using the division style
                                            ], style={'display': 'flex'}),  
                                          ]),
                                
                                # Add Computed graphs
                                # REVIEW3: Observe how we add an empty division and providing an id that will be updated during callback
                                html.Div([], id ='plot1'),
    
                                html.Div([
                                        html.Div([], id ='plot2'),
                                        html.Div([], id ='plot3')
                                ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
                                
                                # TODO3: Add a division with two empty divisions inside. See above disvision for example.
                                html.Div([
                                        html.Div([], id ='plot4'),
                                        html.Div([], id ='plot5')
                                ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
                               
                                ])

# Callback function definition
# TODO4: Add 5 ouput components
@app.callback( [Output(component_id = 'plot1', component_property = 'children'),
 Output(component_id = 'plot2', component_property = 'children'),
 Output(component_id = 'plot3', component_property = 'children'),
 Output(component_id = 'plot4', component_property = 'children'),
 Output(component_id = 'plot5', component_property = 'children')],
               [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
                Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')],
               # REVIEW4: Holding output state till user enters all the form information. In this case, it will be chart type and year
               [State("plot1", 'children'), State("plot2", "children"),
                State("plot3", "children"), State("plot4", "children"),
                State("plot5", "children")
               ])
# Add computation to callback function and return graph
def get_graph(chart, year, children1, children2, c3, c4, c5):
      
        # Select data
        df =  airline_data[airline_data['Year']==int(year)]
       
        if chart == 'OPT1':
            # Compute required information for creating graph from the data
            bar_data, line_data, div_data, map_data, tree_data = compute_data_choice_1(df)
            
            # Number of flights under different cancellation categories
            bar_fig = px.bar(bar_data, x='Month', y='Flights', color='CancellationCode', title='Monthly Flight Cancellation')
            
            # TODO5: Average flight time by reporting airline
            line_fig = px.line(line_data, x = 'Month', y = 'AirTime', color = 'Reporting_Airline', title = 'Average monthly flight time (minutes) by airline')
            
            # Percentage of diverted airport landings per reporting airline
            pie_fig = px.pie(div_data, values='Flights', names='Reporting_Airline', title='% of flights by reporting airline')
            
            # REVIEW5: Number of flights flying from each state using choropleth
            map_fig = px.choropleth(map_data,  # Input data
                    locations='OriginState', 
                    color='Flights',  
                    hover_data=['OriginState', 'Flights'], 
                    locationmode = 'USA-states', # Set to plot as US States
                    color_continuous_scale='GnBu',
                    range_color=[0, map_data['Flights'].max()]) 
            map_fig.update_layout(
                    title_text = 'Number of flights from origin state', 
                    geo_scope='usa') # Plot only the USA instead of globe
            
            # TODO6: Number of flights flying to each state from each reporting airline
            tree_fig = px.treemap(tree_data, path=['DestState', 'Reporting_Airline'], 
                      values='Flights',
                      color='Flights',
                      color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                      title='Flight count by airline to destination state'
                )
            
            
            # REVIEW6: Return dcc.Graph component to the empty division
            return [dcc.Graph(figure=tree_fig), 
                    dcc.Graph(figure=pie_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=map_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=bar_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=line_fig)
                   ]
        else:
            # REVIEW7: This covers chart type 2 and we have completed this exercise under Flight Delay Time Statistics Dashboard section
            # Compute required information for creating graph from the data
            avg_car, avg_weather, avg_NAS, avg_sec, avg_late = compute_data_choice_2(df)
            
            # Create graph
            carrier_fig = px.line(avg_car, x='Month', y='CarrierDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average carrrier delay time (minutes) by airline')
            weather_fig = px.line(avg_weather, x='Month', y='WeatherDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average weather delay time (minutes) by airline')
            nas_fig = px.line(avg_NAS, x='Month', y='NASDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average NAS delay time (minutes) by airline')
            sec_fig = px.line(avg_sec, x='Month', y='SecurityDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average security delay time (minutes) by airline')
            late_fig = px.line(avg_late, x='Month', y='LateAircraftDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average late aircraft delay time (minutes) by airline')
            
            return[dcc.Graph(figure=carrier_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=weather_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=nas_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=sec_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=late_fig)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't want to trim my code as I wasn't sure where the problem was occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very long and indentation is inconsistent.  I recommend you start using https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I did find your **dash** app does basically work,  it's just a case it either

- blocks because port is already in use.  Restart all kernels to resolve
- doesn't open a browser window to view running app.  Code below will do this for you.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from threading import Timer
    import webbrowser
    Timer(10, webbrowser.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:8050/")).start()
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: That's done the trick! Thank you very much for your tip as well.